# Doctrine_Query is automatically pick additional columns because of that group by is not working symfony

Tags: mysql, symfony

***This is my query builder***

$query = Doctrine_Query:: create()

```
                ->select('e.crowd_pm_id as pmId,a.employee_id,sum((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, a.punch_in_user_time, a.punch_out_user_time)/60)) AS as durationCount')
                ->from('AttendanceRecord a')
                ->leftJoin('a.Employee e')
                ->addWhere("a.punch_in_user_time >=  '". $searchClues['punchInUserTime']."'")
                ->addWhere("a.punch_out_user_time <= '".$searchClues['punchOutUserTime'] ."' OR a.punch_out_user_time IS NULL")
                ->andWhere('e.crowd_pm_id IS NOT NULL')
                ->groupBy('e.crowd_pm_id , a.employee_id');
```

***Out put should be***

```
SELECT h.crowd_pm_id as pmId,o.employee_id, SUM((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, o.punch_in_user_time, o.punch_out_user_time)/60)) AS o__1 FROM ohrm_attendance_record o LEFT JOIN hs_hr_employee h ON o.employee_id = h.emp_number WHERE (o.punch_in_user_time >= '2017-01-26' AND (o.punch_out_user_time <= '2017-01-27' OR o.punch_out_user_time IS NULL) AND h.crowd_pm_id IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY h.crowd_pm_id , o.employee_id
```

***Error message that I get***

> Blockquote : 
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'intcrowd_db.o.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by. Failing Query: "SELECT o.id AS o__id, o.employee_id AS o__employee_id, h.emp_number AS h__emp_number, h.crowd_pm_id AS h__0, h.crowd_pm_id AS h__0, SUM((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, o.punch_in_user_time, o.punch_out_user_time)/60)) AS o__1 FROM ohrm_attendance_record o LEFT JOIN hs_hr_employee h ON o.employee_id = h.emp_number WHERE (o.punch_in_user_time >= '2017-01-19' AND (o.punch_out_user_time <= '2017-01-20' OR o.punch_out_user_time IS NULL) AND h.crowd_pm_id IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY h.crowd_pm_id , o.employee_id"

```
(Their is additional columns in the query that auto picked up)
```

I'm using wamp

1. php version 5.6.25
2. mysql version 5.7.14
3. symfony version < 1.4
4. windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurs because of your symfony version not compatible with mysql version.Please use mysql version below 5.5